# How to correctly inject HttpClient into a dependency?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am starting to learn testing Angular services. There is an official example in the Angular [Testing Guide](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jxjddgynnyy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). But in the example, a simpler version of the dependence of one service on another service.

```
  /// HeroService method tests begin ///
  describe('#getHeroes', () => {
    let expectedHeroes: Hero[];

    beforeEach(() => {
      heroService = TestBed.inject(HeroService);
      expectedHeroes = [
        { id: 1, name: 'A' },
        { id: 2, name: 'B' },
       ] as Hero[];
    });

    it('should return expected heroes (called once)', () => {
      heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
        heroes => expect(heroes).toEqual(expectedHeroes, 'should return expected heroes'),
        fail
      );
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(heroService.heroesUrl);
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
      req.flush(expectedHeroes);
    });
```

I have a TerritoryApiService with a set of methods for working with a list of territories.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TerritoryApiService {
  private nameApi: string = 'territory';
  constructor(private apiclient : ApiclientService) {}

public GetStaffTerritories(dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date) {
    let parameters = new Map();
    parameters.set('dateFrom', dateFrom.toISOString());
    parameters.set('dateTo', dateTo.toISOString());
    return this.apiclient.doPostT<StaffTerritory[]>(this.nameApi, 'GetStaffTerritories', parameters);
  }
}
```

The TerritoryApiService depends on the ApiClientService, and the HttpClient and AppConfig containing the URL is passed to the ApiClientService.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiclientService {
  private apiurl: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) config: AppConfig) { 
    this.apiurl = config.apiEndpoint;
  }

public doPostT<T> (url: string, method :string, parameters: Map<string,string> ) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let httpParams = new HttpParams();
    if (parameters != undefined) {
      for (let [key, value] of parameters) {
        httpParams = httpParams.append(key, value);
    }
    } 
    return this.http.post<T>(this.apiurl +'/v1/' + url + '/' + method, httpParams, {
      headers: headers,
      params: httpParams
    })
  }
}

const appConfig: AppConfig = {
    apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint
  };

export const environment = {
  production: false, 
  apiEndpoint: 'https://localhost:44390/api'
};
```

Please tell me how to properly prepare the test (configure all dependencies)? Because now I have two situations:

1.If I just specify ApiclientService in the provide section, then the test passes with an error, because appConfig is undefined (the URL becomes 'undefined/v1/territory/GetStaffTerritories')

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ 
        TerritoryApiService, 
        ApiclientService,
        { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: APP_CONFIG } 
      ]
    });
```

2. if I specify what to use as the ApiclientService, then I need to explicitly create the HttpClient and pass it to the constructor. In this case, an error appears in the test that the post method is undefined. So HttpClient needs to be created?

   const appConfig: AppConfig = {
   apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint
   };
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
   providers: [
   TerritoryApiService,
   { provide: ApiclientService, useValue: new ApiclientService(httpClient, appConfig) },
   { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: APP_CONFIG }
   ]});

Complete test code

```js
describe('TerritoryApiService', () => {
  let service: TerritoryApiService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  const staffTerritoriesStub: StaffTerritory[] = [{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: 'StaffTerritory', 
    regionCode: 29, 
    createDate: new Date(),
    creatorId: 0,
    dateFrom: new Date(),
    dateTo: null,
    dateToSelect: new Date(),
    dateFromChanger: 0,
    dateToChanger: null, 
  }];

  const appConfig: AppConfig = {
    apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ 
        TerritoryApiService, 
        { provide: ApiclientService, useValue: new ApiclientService(httpClient, appConfig) },
        { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: APP_CONFIG } 
      ]
    });
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(TerritoryApiService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });


  describe('#GetStaffTerritories', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      service = TestBed.inject(TerritoryApiService);
    });

    it('should return expected heroes (called once)', () => {
      service.GetStaffTerritories(new Date(), new Date()).subscribe(
        staffTerritories => expect(staffTerritories).toEqual(staffTerritoriesStub, 'should return expected staffTerritories'),
        fail
      );
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/v1/' + 'territory' + '/' + 'GetStaffTerritories');
      req.flush(staffTerritoriesStub);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're providing `AppConfig` wrong and in your situation, I would not mock `ApiclientService` with `new ApiclientService(httpClient, appConfig)` because you're giving actual implementations of `HttpClient` with `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Try this:

```
describe('TerritoryApiService', () => {
  let service: TerritoryApiService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  const staffTerritoriesStub: StaffTerritory[] = [{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: 'StaffTerritory', 
    regionCode: 29, 
    createDate: new Date(),
    creatorId: 0,
    dateFrom: new Date(),
    dateTo: null,
    dateToSelect: new Date(),
    dateFromChanger: 0,
    dateToChanger: null, 
  }];

  const appConfig: AppConfig = {
    apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint // make sure environment.apiEndpoint is defined
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ 
        TerritoryApiService, 
        ApiclientService, // provide the actual ApiclientService since you have the dependencies 
        { provide: AppConfig, useValue: appConfig } // this line needs to change to this 
      ]
    });
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(TerritoryApiService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });


  describe('#GetStaffTerritories', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      service = TestBed.inject(TerritoryApiService);
    });

    it('should return expected heroes (called once)', (done) => { // add done here to have a handle to let Jasmine know when we are done with our assertions
      service.GetStaffTerritories(new Date(), new Date()).subscribe(
        staffTerritories => {
          expect(staffTerritories).toEqual(staffTerritoriesStub, 'should return expected 
          staffTerritories');
          done(); // I would put a done here to ensure that the subscribe block was traversed
       },
        fail
      );
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/v1/' + 'territory' + '/' + 'GetStaffTerritories');
      req.flush(staffTerritoriesStub);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you very much